# Can I point jshint to /public in Play Framework's build.sbt?

Tags: playframework

I'd like to get the new-ish addition of JShint working, but in my simple project, the JS is all located in /public.  Of course, the activator command jsHint only looks in assets.

At some point I will definitely move my JS to assets and use a closure compiler, however in the mean time, is there a way in build.sbt I can point the jshint plugin to /public, instead of /assets? I'd really like the benefit of the built-in js linting straight away.

I have looked through the source https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint#sbt-jshint however, my project is Java based, and my Scala is pretty raw still.